# Iterate Session variable in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have a .net MVC Project. I assigned a `List` to a session variable. And in the View, i use jquery to iterate the data in the session variable.

ie,

```
var doctors = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["DoctorList"]));

doctorCount = doctors.length; 

for(i=0;i<doctorCount ; i++) 
{
     var totalinvoice =0; 
     rows = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'>"+ (parseInt(i, 10)+1) +"</td><td colspan='6'><b>" + doctors[i].D_Name + "</b></td></tr>" 
     $(rows).appendTo("#tbl_doctorwise tbody"); 
}
```

This code some time gives null even if the session variable contains list value. But sometimes it works.

Is there any other method to loop a session variable in the mvc view (jquery)?

how I get the session value in jquery ??? ( session variable contains list )

Comment: softwares are not moody. It either works or it doesn't. The above code looks fine to me. Can you share the looping part you mentioned? It's possible something is wrong there.

Comment: var doctorCount = doctors.length;
for(i=0;i<doctorCount ; i++)
{
       var totalinvoice =0;
       rows = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'>"+ (parseInt(i, 10)+1) +</td><td colspan='6'><b>" + doctors[i].D_Name + "</b></td></tr>"
                                $(rows).appendTo("#tbl_doctorwise tbody"); }

Comment: Do you really need jquery for this? Why aren't you looping through the `Session["DoctorList"]` and populate the `tr` where the <table> is created? Share your controller action method that returns this `View`. Also, you should use a `ViewModel` or `ViewBag` for this.

Comment: Actually The data is not coming  on run time not in the page load. I need to pass two list to the view. one list i passed throw the ajax, and the other one i passed using session.

Comment: Where did the ajax call come from? You need to share all the relevant code to make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: $.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action("GetDoctorwiseReport","Home")",
data: { fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate },
type: "post",
datatype: "json",
success: function (data)
{
var r = "";
var drs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["DoctorList"]));
var dCount=doctors.length;
for(i=0;i<dCount ;i++)
{r= "<tr><td >" + drs[i].D_Name + "</td</tr>"
$(r).appendTo("#tbl_doctor tbody");
for(j=0; j<data.length ;j++)
{if(drs [i].DoctorCode == data[j].DoctorCode)
{
r= "<tr><td >"+data[j].WONo+"</td><td >"+data[j].HospitalName +"</td></tr>";
$(r).appendTo("#tbl_doctor tbody");
}}}}})

Comment: Update the question with the details!

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an ajax call and setting this session item in your action method, it won't available in your original view as that view code was already executed when you requested the action method for that view.

What you should do is, instead of setting this data in session, return that as json from your action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDoctorwiseReport(DateTime fromDate,DateTime toDate)
{
  var doctorList = new List<Doctor>();
  //populate this list now
  return Json(doctorList);
}
```

and now in your ajax call's success handler will receive this data and you can loop through them.

```
 success: function(data) {
     $.each(data,function(ind,item)
     {
        //build your html here as needed.
        console.log(item);
     });
 }
```

Comment: I Solved the issue using ,

<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        var doctors= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["DoctorList"]))
        $.each(doctors, function (index, value)
        {
            var totalinvoice =0; 
     rows = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'>"+ (parseInt(i, 10)+1) +"</td><td colspan='6'><b>" + value.D_Name + "</b></td></tr>" 
     $(rows).appendTo("#tbl_doctorwise tbody"); 
        }) 
    });
</script>

Comment: I need to pass two different lists, so that i used session for one list.

Comment: There is no data when the fist time. But if i reload the page i data get displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
$(function () 
{ 
    var doctors= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(HttpContext.Current.Session["DoctorLis‌​t"])) 
    $.each(doctors, function (index, value) 
    { 
        var totalinvoice =0; rows = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'>"+ (parseInt(i, 10)+1) +"</td><td colspan='6'><b>" + value.D_Name + "</b></td></tr>" 
        $(rows).appendTo("#tbl_doctorwise tbody"); 
    }) 
}); 
</script>
```